# Google Place Autocomplete API in Ionic 6 Capacitor

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, capacitor

Recently I have been working on an **Ionic** Project. I am very much newbie in this framework.

I need to add the location search autocomplete feature from the **Google Place Autocomplete** api.

So, Is the library available on **Capacitor**. I can't find it in the plugin page.

Any kind of help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Remember that the Capacitor plugins are meant to interact with device Native APIs, for example to work with the Camera, FileSystem... I think that Google Places autocomplete is not directly depending on those Native APIs, so you could use it without any plugin of Capacitor. Also would be helpful that you share some code in order to get a better help.